# Adding a ramp function in R

Tags: r, loops

There are multiple teams in a production plant. A team in a production plant can produce 12 products at the full potential but it takes 12 months for a team to reach full potential.At current we have 100 teams. If we add a team each month, this is how it should look.For each team the productivity should increase by 1/12 per month and stay constant after 12 months.

```
Month       Teams        Teams_Equivalent      
Jan-20       101           100.08                 
Feb-20       102           100.25                 
Mar-20       103           100.50                 
Apr-20       104           100.83                 
May-20       105           101.25                 
Jun-20       106           101.75                 
Jul-20       107           102.33                 
Aug-20       108           103.00                 
Sep-20       109           103.75                 
Oct-20       110           104.58                 
Nov-20       111           105.50                 
Dec -20      112           106.50                 
Jan-21       113           107.50                     
Feb-21       114           108.50
```

I tried to use for loop, something like below and it's not working,

```
a = 1:14
Teams <- 100
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  Teams_Equivalent = Teams_Equivalent*(1/12)
}
print(Teams_Equivalent)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Am unable to get the right values for Teams-Equivalent. Am getting something like this 100.08 then 100.16 then 100.24 but not like what's in the table. I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: You can't use`Teams-Equivalent` as a name. R thinks this means "subtract the variable `Equivalent` from the variable `Teams`

Comment: thanks, Allaan. I will change that

Comment: I'm also perplexed about the output you're getting from the loop.  The statement inside the loop doesn't append a new value to `Teams_Equivalent`; it replaces it entirely.  So the `print()` statement afterward will display only one value (assuming `Teams_Equivalent` started as a single value rather than a vector).  I'm having trouble reconciling that with the "100.08 then 100.16 then 100.24" you described.

Comment: A.S.K thanks and sorry am unable to replicate the exact thing from the code from work. Actually, it's huge piece of code I tried to recreate here in a simple way. I try to edit the question until it's perfect but the end goal is right. That'w what i am exactly trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but this gives what you are asking,

```
a <- 1:14
first_step <-round(cumsum(1:12)/12 +100,2)


for(i in 13:max(a)) {

    first_step[i] <- max(first_step) +1
}

[1] 100.08 100.25 100.50 100.83 101.25 101.75 102.33 103.00 103.75
[10] 104.58 105.50 106.50 107.50 108.50
```