# Adding ramp function in r

Tags: r, function, loops

There are multiple teams in a production plant. A team in a production plant can produce 1 product a month at the full potential but it takes 5 months for a team to reach full potential. Currently we have 100 teams. For each new team the productivity should increase by 1/5 per month and stay constant at 1 after 5 months. We add teams on certain months and we terminate teams on certain months, when we terminate we terminate only the teams which are working at full potential. This is how it should look like, I am trying to calculate teams_equivalent

```
month   teams   changeInTeams   teams_equivalent
1        102       2               100.40
2        101      -1                99.80
3        105       4               101.80
4        103      -2               103.00
5        104       1               107.60
6        105       1               111.40
```

That is:

```
teams_equivalent<-round(cumsum(1:5)/5/changeInTeams/ +teams,2)
```

Comment: Raju you asked a very similar question [last month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313474/adding-a-ramp-function-in-r). Can you please explain why this is different, otherwise this is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Allan, it's different because the other question is a a scenario where we add same number of teams per month and they are all positive. This has 2 different scenarios, the one like which I asked last time but an additional scenario of adding different numbers each month and also terminating teams.